# Google Apps script large data set transfer

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this and help.

I have the following script in use, and recently it has started to fail as the script times out.

```
function transfer() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
 var range = ss.getRange(2,2,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn()); // extend if adding in columns 'A15:AK'
 var data = range.getValues();
  
 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mRhWcIKLiBchNX3tYvn062tUMkRtrWgNQWaXaA8");
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Copy of VTVimport Here');
 ts.getRange(2, 2, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

The volume of data in "sheet1" is currently around 300,000 rows by 20 columns. I have made the script work by breaking it out into 50000 rows at a time, but I am concerned that the data may expand beyond 300000 and this could get missed.

I have read some of the best practices and tips around cashe and arrays, I believe this formula is putting the data into an array to speed it up, but any points as to how to speed up the transfer up would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share more details on what limit you are getting and what is your use case / what have you tried for now?

Comment: this is a time trigger script that is used to update a data feed each morning. The limit I am getting is the script is timing out at 1800s "Error Exceeded maximum execution time". 
I have used the same script but updated the range to look and transfer 50000 rows at a time, with several different triggers completing over a 2hr period. 
Hope that answers the question.

Comment: Probably should start using Sheets API